# different color backgrounds in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, colors

I followed a tutorial to make a basic notepad application so I could get the hang of using the ActionBar, Intents and other Android basics. After finishing the tutorial I've been messing around with the UI, allowing the user to assign background colors to different notes. 
Currently when a user creates a new note an InfoDialog menu comes up and the user chooses a color for the background of the new note. 
The choice for the color is concatted onto a key value for retrieving notes in shared preferences so i can split the key and reuse the choice value whenever necessary.

Im currently trying to also make the background of the note in the listview of my main activity display the same background color but i'm not sure how to start this. Ive seen a lot of talk about using getView from the adapter and it seems like that would work fine for me if i pass the background color choice into the getView method and use if statements or a switch case to set the list background.

Here is some relevant code to the application:

```
public class NotePadd extends SherlockListActivity
{


private static final int EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST = 1001;
private static final int MENU_DELETE_ID = 1002;
private int currentNoteId;
private NoteDataSource dataSource;
private infoDialog info;
int bgChoice;

List<NoteItem> notes;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_padd);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    dataSource = new NoteDataSource(this);

    refreshDisplay();

}

private void refreshDisplay()
{
    notes = dataSource.findAll();
    ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>    
    (this,R.layout.list_item_layout,notes);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getSherlock().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.note_padd, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.action_create)
    {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new infoDialog();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "info");

    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void createNote()
{
    NoteItem note = NoteItem.getNew(bgChoice);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,NoteEditorActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("key",note.getKey());
    i.putExtra("text",note.getText());
    i.putExtra("bg", note.getbg());
    startActivityForResult(i, EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    NoteItem note = notes.get(position);

    String[] bgSplit = note.getKey().split("\\s");
    int bgTemp = Integer.parseInt(bgSplit[3]);

    Log.i("BGTEMP: ",bgSplit[3]);

    Intent i = new Intent(this,NoteEditorActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("key",note.getKey());
    i.putExtra("text",note.getText());
    i.putExtra("bg", bgTemp);
    startActivityForResult(i, EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode==EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        NoteItem note = new NoteItem();
        note.setKey(data.getStringExtra("key"));
        note.setText(data.getStringExtra("text"));
        dataSource.update(note);
        refreshDisplay();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    currentNoteId = (int)info.id;
    menu.add(0,MENU_DELETE_ID,0,"Delete");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId()==MENU_DELETE_ID)
    {
        NoteItem note = notes.get(currentNoteId);
        dataSource.remove(note);
        refreshDisplay();
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

// ----------------------infoDialog----------------------//

private class infoDialog extends DialogFragment
{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.color_prompt)
               .setItems(R.array.colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                   {
                      bgChoice = which;
                      createNote();
                      dialog.dismiss();

                   }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }

}
}
```

List Item Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity ="center_vertical"
    android:padding ="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_noteitem_edit"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bgblue">
</TextView>
```

Theres a few more Activities and XML files im happy to share if necessary. I feel like getView() is what I need to use but ive only just started using Adapters.

Comment: Just set the background color of your parent layout on the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ArrayAdapter's getView method must be overridden for this.

```
private TextView mNoteTextView; 
ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>(this,R.layout.list_item_layout,notes){
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
     View v = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
     mNoteTextView = (TextView)v;
     NoteItem item = getItem(position);
     int noteBG = item.getbg();
     mNoteTextView.setBackground(//get Drawable of the colour);
       //or
     mNoteTextView.setBackgroundColor(//the colour you want to set);
     return v;
    }
};
```

And instead of calling refreshDisplay() to update data, call:

```
void updateData(){
    ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>)getListAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If the colour is saved in a colors.xml file, then to obtain Drawable do:

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.colors.light_blue);
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I could not for the life of me figure out how to override the getView method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for dynamic coloring like this, you will need to set the background color of the `convertView` inside of `getView(...)` each time it is called.

One thing to note is that you won't pass anything into the getView() method yourself as it's called directly by the ListView.  The objects that you give your adapter will need to provide either the color itself or some data that can map to a color so that you can access that inside of getView().

For handling more than one stated (pressed, etc) you will want to use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) that represents the colors for each state.